# Python CSV Module Issue With JSON

Tags: python, json, csv

I am using the python `csv` module to create a csv where some of the values are `json` strings. However the `csv` module's quoting is totally breaking the json:

```
import csv
import json
writer = csv.writer(open('tmp', 'w'))
writer.writerow([json.dumps([{'a' : 'b'}])])
```

The outputted json is broken, as you can see:

```
cat tmp
> "[{""a"": ""b""}]"

import json
json.loads("[{""a"": ""b""}]")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 2)
```

And `csv` objects to turning quoting off:

```
import csv
import json
writer = csv.writer(open('tmp', 'w'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
writer.writerow([json.dumps([{u'a' : u'b'}])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

Has anyone else encountered this? Do `json` and `csv` just not play well together? (It's not my idea to store `json` stirngs in `csv` files.. something I just need to deal with right now). Unfortunately, these csvs I am creating contain hash digests and all sorts of other complicated stuff so all the `sed` or `awk`ish type solutions to fix the json I've tried have failed or messed up something else..

Comment: Drop `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` argument.

Comment: Right, but then the json is still broken by quoting.

Comment: Can't you change the quote character to `'`?

Comment: @qwwqwwq, You will get correct json if you use csv.reader.

Comment: you're right, the other script that was throwing the exception wasn't using csv.reader.. what a mess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use `"` as your quote character.  Use something else:

```
with open('tmp', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quotechar="'")
```

Really, this just tidy's things up a bit.  When you read the data back in, you first need to "unquote" it by reading the data via `csv.reader`.  That should give you back the strings you put in which are valid `json`.

Comment: setting quotechar to anything other than `'"'` fixes the issue, my other problem was that the other script that reads this is was NOT using `csv.reader`, which also solves this